# Saving captcha from input field with selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, save, captcha

I need to save captcha to disk using selenium (under ubuntu). I already logged in at a site as a user. I know that selenium can not work with "Save as" dialog window normally. Which way to save captcha is simplest? (Maybe through JS? How? Or there are another variants?). I will be grateful for reply.

```
<input type="image" alt="" src="/user/captcha" id="captcha" name="captcha">
```

Comment: What use would the image of the CAPTCHA solve, out of interest?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Need to download screenshot and cut it.